# why google api weather is delayed

Tags: xml

for example for

`http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Moscow&hl=en`

I've got

```
<current_conditions>
  <condition data="Clear"/>
  <temp_f data="50"/>
  <temp_c data="10"/>
  <humidity data="Humidity: 76%"/>
  <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/>
  <wind_condition data="Wind: N at 11 mph"/>
</current_conditions>
<forecast_conditions>
  <day_of_week data="Sun"/>
  <low data="43"/>
  <high data="57"/>
  <icon data="/ig/images/weather/rain.gif"/>
  <condition data="Rain"/>
</forecast_conditions>
```

Sunday is in `forecast_conditions` but Sunday is today. So `current_conditions` are for Saturday.
Why it has 1 day delay?

Comment: google's weather api is deprecated and not supported by google. Use yahoo's instead :)

Comment: Afaik, it's not deprecated and in use for Android phones weather widgets.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the forecast is for the *rest* of today, instead of starting tomorrow.

I notice that at this current moment, it is not quite midnight in Moscow. It might be interesting for you to wait another 35 minutes to see what happens then.